# Blender3.5 Render not working

Tags: rendering

Im trying to render my animation in blender and everytime I hit render its just the grey window without even trying to render it and then it crashes, in the viewport going to rendered view work fine though. Ive tried changing clipping distance, adding in a different camera and simpifying everything, nothings working, never had this problem before.[image]